# Making Facebook Like button iFrame background transparent over flash in IE8

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

Been trying to float FB Like button iFrame over flash content, used allowTransparency and works nicely in FF and Chrome, but in IE8 the iFrame still has a white background, I use
swfobject to load the flash.

Any pointers in fixing that greatly appreciated!

iFrame & swfobject Source:

```
     <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%MYAPP;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font=verdana&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px; position: absolute; background-color:transparent; top: 50px; left: 623px ; z-index:1255; allowTransparency:true;"  ></iframe>


swfobject.embedSWF("my.swf", "mySWF", "753", "774", "10.0", "#000000", null, null, {name:"mySWF",wmode:"opaque"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using allowtransparency as a style but it needs to be an attribute of your iframe. `<iframe allowtransparency="true"></iframe>` 
There may be a delay, but once the page is loaded, the background of your iframe should be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I actually don't think you are allowed to do that. If you check Facebook's [branding guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php), it says on the like button usage, that you aren't to modify the image.

In case I misunderstood - do you have a live link to what you are trying to achieve, where it is working on FF and Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm afraid I can't post the live link yet as the client/product havent launched, but here's a screen cap of how it shows in FireFox and IE8.    http://i871.photobucket.com/albums/ab277/Hofuzz/compare.jpg